# Contents of _site not generating same page as jekyll serve?

Tags: jekyll

On the jekyll website the instructions to deploy the website is the following,

```
    simply run the jekyll command and copy the generated _site folder to the root 
folder of your hosting account.
```

When I copy the _site folder to public_html on my university webserver, I do not get the same page that I was getting when I ran `jekyll serve` locally. In particular, it appears the css was missing.

Do I need to copy something else to deploy the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assets (css, js, image) are certainly missing some path.

Your **_config.yml** should content **baseurl: /yoursite/path** your site url is on the form : **http://youruniv.edu/yoursite/path/**.

And calling your assets should be done like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/javascripts/scripts.js"></script>
```